# WKWebView is only displays apple site

Tags: ios, xcode, webkit, plist, wkwebview

I have been checking apple doc: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview
and stack's answers and I have received any answer in using apple official apple documentation, and I only can access Apple's website and nothing else besides that.

here is my code(as it been published at apples)

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {

    var webView: WKWebView!

    override func loadView() {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let myURL = URL(string:"https://www.google.com")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        webView.load(myRequest)
    }
}
```

**I have added the p.list options:**

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>https://www.google.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

and nothing else works-except apple website
and I have not found a relevant answer online
as I mention I have searched in apple doc' and in here.
 thanks for all of your thoughts!!

Comment: Did you use the ios simulator?
I suffered the same symptoms. But when I installed the app on the my iPhone, it worked.
I think it's a simulator bug. [My Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKtMw.png)
[My Phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Q8vw.jpg)

Comment: you are right. i have been using the simulator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simulator bug
works in a real device